# real-time search in telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am writing a telegram bot with [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf).

I want an inline search in my bot and I want to show the result of the searching in real-time.
Something like what @gif or @bing do.
They show the result of the search in real-time and you can click on each item you want to select.
I don't know the name of module/function I should use(I don't know where to begin!)

Can anyone help me and tell what to use and where to start from?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @Sean I have no idea how to do this.I couldn't find any tutorial or guide for this.I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "Inline mode" method in [Telegram Bot Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery) and you set bot mode in inline-mode via BotFather so you can use all inline-mode methods in your bot.